# How to compare dates in SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I want to query the database within a stored procedure with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT date1 FROM table INTO dates
WHERE date1 < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
AND date1 > CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()), 112);
```

I get an error on the WHERE clause, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: what value date1 contains?

Comment: What is the format of the date1 column?  I assume not datetime?

Comment: what error you get on where clause?

Comment: I getting an error on syntax.

Comment: date1 is type DATE in SQL.

Comment: date1 is arbitrary in this case.

Comment: We know you get error but what exactly the error states???

Comment: 201: A syntax error has occurred. This in an Informix database by the way.

Comment: What are you trying to do, precisely?  I don't recall a CONVERT function in Informix, and neither GETDATE nor DATEADD is native (though they might exist as compatibility measures).  The `112` is inscrutable to me.  If `date1` is of type `DATE`, then you might be intending to write `WHERE date1 < TODAY AND date1 > TODAY - 4`, which is sufficient since Informix has a nice sensible system for handling DATE types.  DATETIME is more verbose.

Comment: I am trying to obtain the any dates that are between a range of the current day to the an amount  days specified in the query (back 4 days for example). Essentially, I would like to return a true if any days exist in that range otherwise return a false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax erro is because the `INTO` is wrong.

1) But as @Jonathan has mentioned , the funcitions GETDAT, CONVERT, DATEADD 
aren't native and not exists at INFORMIX database. Unless you have create it...
  2) The "dates" should be a variable at your SPL.

3) The SELECT should return only 1 row....

```
SELECT date1 INTO dates FROM table 
WHERE date1 < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
AND date1 > CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()), 112);
```

This should be a valid Informix syntax:

```
SELECT date1 INTO dates FROM table 
WHERE date1 < today
AND date1 > today - 4 units day ;
```

For more information about the syntax , please check at the [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm)

Comment: Oddly enough, I was able to create the stored procedure with DATEADD, GETDATE and CONVERT. I will not know if the query will actually work though yet until I use it for some data.

Comment: I see this syntax as MS SQL SERVER and probably will not work. If date1 is date or datetime data type , you able replace the convert+getdate to `TODAY`keyword. and at second convert() expression you can replace it with this `today -4 units day` .

Comment: Can post what this code would look like, not sure what mean by `today -4 units day`

Comment: about the select only returning one row, how would just create a sql statement that only returns one row,
`SELECT date1 INTO dates FROM table 
WHERE date1 < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
AND date1 > CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()), 112);`

Would IF conditional be needed?

Comment: I was able to utilize UNITS DAY to solve the problem I was having, there are some key differences with SQL with Informix.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming date1 is datetime type then Use Between

```
SELECT date1  INTO dates FROM table
WHERE date1 BETWEEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()), 112) AND
                     CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112);
```

if date1 is not datetime, then convert it to then Use Between

```
   SELECT date1 INTO dates FROM table 
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), date1, 112) BETWEEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()), 112) AND
                         CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112);
```